# SalesForce with Android?

Tags: android, salesforce

I want connect sales Force from my Android Program please suggest which one is correct way to achieve this I am new to sales Force I have some knowledge in Android Application Developement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You may find this helpful; [Getting Started with the Mobile SDK for Android](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_Android). And please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to know which kind of questions can be asked here.

Answer (score 5):

You definitely want to use the REST API for mobile apps. The SOAP API is really heavy, and is better for Server-to-Server integrations. The best way to get started building an Android app for Salesforce.com is to take a look at the Salesforce Mobile SDK for Android:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK

There's a very helpful getting started PDF linked on that page.

However, the SDK is meant mostly for starting new apps, so you'll have some work ahead of you integrating it into an existing application. The main things you want are the oAuth 2.0 User-Agent login and REST wrappers.

You may also find this app useful -- I put it together for a presentation at Dreamforce '11, which was shortly before the Mobile SDK for Android came out, so I wrote the oAuth and REST stuff myself. Might be a simpler starting point for you.

https://github.com/tomgersic/DreamforcengerHunt

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also, if you want, the Dreamforce session is on Youtube here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTNRO24-s7g

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the RESTful interface or the SOAP webservices. The latter is a bit easier to deal with IMHO.
Under setup in salesforce, [download the partner or enterprise WSDL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm) ([partner = generic, enterprise = specific for your SF-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197197/salesforce-different-wsdl-files-and-when-to-use)). Now with [wsdl2java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2javawizard/) you can create Stubs for those wsdl entries. Import those into your android app and use them. See [here](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Java_Partner_WSDL_Samples_10.0) for a Java Exampe by Salesforce.com.

Be sure your user has the permission to "do API". You might want to look into SSO if you want to make a "production"/commercial app. Also, to login, remember to use the correct password, you might need to add the API key (generate using the Setup tab in SF). Hope this helps.

Comment: is there any android sample ?

Comment: I don't have a android example, no. But I suggest you use any basic textview / button sample and combine it with the steps I outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out some of the open-source SDK projects the developer evangelists have added to the [forcedotcom github](https://github.com/forcedotcom)

Lots of good examples on different platforms, including [android with phonegap/html5](https://github.com/forcedotcom/callback-android) and a [native SDK for android](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android) (iOS and Android) to get you past authentication and onto building your app.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Provides mobile SDK for development on mobile device, here is the link for android SDK:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Mobile_SDK_for_Android

You need to:

1. Download SDK.
2. Add a sample project included in SDK's native/SampleApps folder(make sure you check include to the workspace while importing the project).
3. Get your remote access form salesforce and update in your app.

   --This should get you started with a sample app form salsforce.

After this you need to modify existing code to your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to trailhead and start browsing on it, while working with your own application you will have to learn a lot about smartStore and smartSync,

I did implemented A smartStore App with using salesforce as database provider, if you want i can upload it to drive and share a link to you and
if you have any doubts about using or understanding the flow be free to ask..

Comment: Share the link.